# Is this set a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

"The Set of all continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$"

How do I determine this? Do I think of possible functions which have outputs between $0$ and $1$, and determine if the inputs are real numbers?

Comment: when they say continuous on an interval, they mean the INPUT is inside that interval. Nothing's said about the output interval, except that it most not be sliced because the function's continuous

Comment: Seems like you have a confusion, formally the set you have to check if it is a vector space is
$$
C([0,1])= \left\{ f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{F} \  \big| \ f \  \text{ is continuous }\right\}
$$
where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, usually $\mathbb{F}$ stands for $\mathbb{R}$ or  $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 2):

Note:

> **Definition 1**:  $f$ is a continuous function on the interval $[0,1]$ if and only if $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x) = f(c)$ for all $c\in[0,1]$.
>
> **Property 1**:  $\lim\limits_{x\to c} (f(x)+g(x)) = \lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x) + \lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x)$
>
> I.e. the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits (assuming the limits exist in the first place).
>
> **Property 2**:  $\lim\limits_{x\to c} \alpha f(x) = \alpha\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)$
>
> I.e. scalar multiples can be pulled outside of the limits.

If you have not seen either of these two properties before, take a moment and practice trying to prove them.

You are tasked with trying to prove that "*if $f$ and $g$ are both continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$, then $\alpha f + \beta g$ is also a continuous function on the interval $[0,1]$*."  I.e. is it true that $\lim\limits_{x\to c} (\alpha f(x) + \beta g(x)) = \alpha f(c)+\beta g(c)$ for all $c\in[0,1]$?

The result is almost immediate from the definition and properties listed above.

---

Proof:

Let $f$ and $g$ both be continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$ and pick any $c\in[0,1]$.  Let $h(x)=\alpha f(x)+\beta g(x)$.  You have then that:

$\begin{array}{}\lim\limits_{x\to c}h(x)=
\lim\limits_{x\to c} \alpha f(x) + \beta g(x) &= \lim\limits_{x\to c} \alpha f(x) + \lim\limits_{x\to c} \beta g(x)&\text{by property 1}\\
&=\alpha\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x) + \beta\lim\limits_{x\to c}g(x)&\text{by property 2}\\
&=\alpha f(c)+\beta g(c)&\text{by continuity}\\
&=h(c)&\text{by how we defined}~h\end{array}$

Since $c$ was selected arbitrarily, this shows that for all $c\in[0,1]$ you have $\lim\limits_{x\to c}h(x)=h(c)$, and $h$ therefore satisfies the definition of being continuous on the interval.

Thus showing that any linear combination of continuous functions on an interval is again a continuous function on that same interval and that our set is indeed a vector space.

Comment: I have seen those properties and understand their application, but I don't think I understand them fully, because I have no idea where I would start to go about proving them. Can you help me out here?

Comment: @Hannah proof added.  The property is so familiar that we don't usually bother proving it.  It is worth proving at least once for practice properties 1 and 2 using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits, but most analysis books will include that as an example as opposed to an exercise.

Comment: As for proving property $1$, suppose both $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $c$.  Then for each $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, there is a $\delta_f$ and a $\delta_g$ for $f$ and $g$ respectively such that $|x-c|<\delta_f\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (similarly for $g$).  For $f+g$, take $\delta = \min\{\delta_f,\delta_g\}$.  Then $|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)+g(x)-f(c)-g(c)|\leq |f(x)-f(c)|+|g(x)-g(c)|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$.  Therefore proving that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta$ for $f+g$ such that...

Comment: For property 2, suppose $f$ is continuous at $c$.  Then for each $\frac{\epsilon}{|\alpha|}>0$, there is a $\delta$ such that $|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\frac{\epsilon}{|\alpha|}$.  So, for $\alpha f(x)$, take the same $\delta$ and you get $|x-c|<\delta \Rightarrow |\alpha f(x)-\alpha f(c)|=|\alpha||f(x)-f(c)|<|\alpha|\frac{\epsilon}{|\alpha|}=\epsilon$, proving that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta$ for $\alpha f$ such that...

Answer (score 0):

The set of all real valued functions on any set is a vector space under pointwise addition. So all you must check is if your space of continuous functions is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.